# Toggle W3Schools responsive topnav after click on item

Tags: javascript, html, css

To start I'm absolutely no hero with javascript.

I implemented a [responsive topnav example from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp) on a [website](http://test.ambassadorsofbruges.com) I'm building right now, but would love to know how to hide it after clicking on one of the menu items (as most will link to items on the same page, so no refresh there).

P.S. I've looked through a lot of other questions, but I just think this particular question probably has a very simple solution which would also be really usefull to be added on W3Schools.

Comment: you want to hide the nav bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will close your nav after clicking a link.

```
var topNav = document.querySelector('#myTopnav');
topNav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    topNav.classList.remove('responsive');
  }
});
```

The other issue where only one menu item fills the entire list height is a `CSS` problem. You need to remove `height: 100%` when viewing the navigation in small screen dimenstions.

```css
.navbar a {
  height: 100%;
}
```

After I commented that line out, things look fine.

[image]

Comment: I added it just after the first script and it indeed toggles the menu back to just the bar again. Only problem is.. it only shows one menu item with the full menu list height.
(It's live now at [link](http://test.ambassadorsofbruges.com) )

Comment: @PascalGerritsen I noticed that, too, but that was an issue before the `JavaScript` change. You have `.navbar a { height: 100%; }`

Comment: Solved. Thanks!