# Toggle W3Schools menu after clicking not working, due to smooth scroll jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

For a simple website I followed the [W3Schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp) about how to create a responsive hamburger menu. To close it, I found this [simple solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153590/toggle-w3schools-responsive-topnav-after-click-on-item) posted on stack overflow.

```
var topNav = document.querySelector('#myTopnav');
topNav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
    topNav.classList.remove('responsive');
  }
});
```

But it does not seem to work for me.
I even altered my website to fit the exact same structure of the example showed in the threat.

Now I figured out, that it does work once I delete a jQuery code for smooth scrolling.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav a[href*=\\#]').bind('click', function(s) {
    s.preventDefault(); 
    var target = $(this).attr("href"); 

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: ( $(target).offset().top - 50 ) 
    }, 600, function() {
      location.hash = target;
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Any idea how I could have them both work next to each other?

Comment: preventDefault does cancel the event bubble, so the event listener does not receive the event.

Comment: Thanks bradbury9, this does not appear to solve it for me.
Without that line, smooth-scroll still works, but the menu still does not close.

Comment: I think it's working now as intended: clicking a menu link closes the menu and smooth scrolls to the anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>As **@bradbury9** pointed out in his comment to your question, taking out `s.preventDefault()` does solve the problem.</strike> Look in the following snippet:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}

// var topNav = document.querySelector('#myTopnav');
// topNav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
//   if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
//     topNav.classList.remove('responsive');
//   }
// });


// PAY ATTENTION! I changed the selector from nav to div.topnav!
// This is only because the HTML in the snippet is structured this way!
$('div.topnav a[href*=\\#]').on('click', function(s) {

  s.preventDefault();

  // EDIT: added line to "merge" the two functions,
  // so they don't block each other
  $("#myTopnav").removeClass("responsive");

  var target = $(this).attr("href");

  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: ($(target).offset().top - 50)
  }, 1000, function() {
    location.hash = target;
  });

  // return false;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div id="news" style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example: news</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div id="contact" style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example: contact</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
```

On small screens

- the hamburger menu appears,
- opens on click
- if open it closes on the next click
- if you click on a menu item (link), the menu closes

The problem is that you bind two `click` events to the same element, and to process both events at the same time bubbling/propagation is needed. (Of course this causes the problem that the link "will work", as there's nothing preventing it from working.)

The other solution could be that you make one function from the two separate functions, so only one click is needed.

**EDIT**
I edited the snippet so it shows how the functions should be merged, and also edited the first line, so it shows that that wasn't the real answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your effort.
In the sample above, the closing works, but there is no smooth scroll.
(I took it elsewhere and added the necessary id's)

To make the smooth scroll script work, the navigation has to be in side a nav tag.
<nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
Once I do so, the scroll works, but the menu does not close any longer.

This might indeed be the conflict of two click events.
So how do I merge those twos scripts into one?
I'm afraid I'm not savvy enough to do this myself.

Comment: Sorry, but what should this "smooth scroll" do? I don't know it, so I cannot check it whether it works or not... :) If I can check it, then I'll try to merge the two functions. Maybe it's about scrolling to an anchor smoothly?

Comment: Edited my answer: I realized that the HTML markup is not correct for the snippet smooth scroll to work (that's why I thought this is a special "smooth scroll"). Commented out the original part that's not needed, added a line that's needed. Now both requested functions work together :)

Comment: I couldn't post an answer, was on phone, the collaborative nature of SO helped OP, my comment pointed a problem and your answer is complete

Comment: @bradbury9 - I think you pointed out that neither of the two sources is wrong, only together they don't provide a solution :) I hope **warpoholic** can use the result!

Comment: Thank you both @bradbury9 and **muka.gergely** it all works perfectly now.

Comment: Happy that I could help! :)